# Converting HTML into Xliff and vice versa

Tags: html, localization, xliff

I want to convert any HTML file (including images and tables and CSS too) to XLIFF.
I would appreciate if some can tell me how to do this. Please provide some sample example code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the fine tools mentioned above the translation suite "Transolution" also supports conversion of HTML/XML to XLIFF.
It's hosting site have been down for some time but is now up again at this location:
https://bitbucket.org/fredrik_corneliusson/transolution/overview

Transolution runs on both Windows and Linux.

You can find documentation about the filter here:
https://bitbucket.org/fredrik_corneliusson/transolution/src/tip/doc/filters.rst?at=default

As the filter is a command line tool it would be quite easy to call it from code to programatically do the conversion.

Answer (score 2):

There are many translation tools like Trados Studio, OmegaT, Swordfish, etc. that can extract HTML into XLIFF (and merge back the translation). They won't 'convert' images though.

If you are more interested in just getting an XLIFF (as opposed to extract/translate/merge) you can also use `Rainbow` or `Tikal` from Okapi Framework. Now they also support HTML5 and [ITS](http://www.w3.org/TR/its20/).

[Translate Toolkit](http://translate.sourceforge.net/wiki/) also provide support for HTML and `Po` to XLIFF conversion.

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply Sir. As I am New Comer in this Translation, could you please provide me some documentation? Please Show me particular direction so that I can get the Procedure and apply for other file formats.